# Resize an image inside a table based on table size

Tags: html, css

I have a table which images will be put inside. Some of the images will be larger than the width of the table (height doesn't matter). I'm looking for a way to keep the image the same size as the table without stretching the table out. I don't want to set the image width to 100% because then it will make the image wider if it's smaller than the table width. Also, I want to the proportions to stay the same. Any ideas?

Comment: You need CSS.. 
set style to the img: max-width:100%; max-height:100%;

Answer (score 0):

using css;

**Example: style.css** (EITHER OF THE TWO)

about **"img"** by asigning either height or width

```
img {
   max-height:50px;
}
```

---

about table inside either **td** or **th**(depends if you used th)

```
td {
   max-height:50px;
}
```

Read guides here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Comment: I added the style but it didn't resize any images. There must be something I'm missing. Here's what I've got...<style type="text/css">
img {
   max-height:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.gif" />
</body>

Comment: try to check if the file of extension is "GIF", "JPG", "PNG"....but mine works...

<html>
    <head>
  <title>Sample Img Scaler</title>
  <style type="text/css"> img { max-height:50px; } </style> </head> 
 </head>
 <body><img src="EXISTING_PHYSICAL.jpg" /></body>
</html>

Comment: That worked for me. I guess I had to have the style in the same line for some reason. weird

Comment: if it worked then you may check / or +1 so that GUEST will now where the SOLUTION was

Answer (score 0):

adjust the height of img to the height of `<tr>`, e.g.

```
tr {
height:40px;
}
tr img{
height:40px;
}
```